# View not working, Passing object to view error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on a project utilizing MVC4 and EF Data First in VS2013. I am getting this error when trying to pass my object to the view.

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[<>f__AnonymousType3`4[System.String,System.Nullable`1[System.Int32],System.Nullable`1[System.Int32],System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[TitansMVCWithBootStrap.Models.Player_Game_Stats]'

I am not sure how to fix this, any suggest would help. Thanks

**Controller**

```
 public class PlayerGameStatsController : Controller
{
    private Context db = new Context();

    // GET: PlayerGameStats/Details/5

    public ActionResult Details(int gid=19, int sid = 11)
    {

        var playerGameStats = from pgs in db.PlayerGameStats
                              join p in db.Players on pgs.Player_id equals p.id_player
                              where pgs.SeasonId == 11 && pgs.GameNumber == 19
                              select new
                              {
                                  p.PlayerName,
                                  pgs.PlateAppearance,
                                  pgs.Runs,
                                  pgs.Hits
                              };


        return View(playerGameStats);

    }
```

**Model**

```
 public class Player_Game_Stats
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    public int Player_id { get; set; }
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public int GameNumber { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> PlateAppearance { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Runs { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> HR { get; set; }
    public int Hits{ get; set; }

    //[ForeignKey("id_player")]
    //public virtual Players Player { get; set; }
}
}
```

**View**

```
@model IEnumerable<TitansMVCWithBootStrap.Models.Player_Game_Stats>
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Details";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Details</h2>

<table class="table table-striped">

<tr>

 <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PlayerName)
    </th>
 <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PlateAppearance)
    </th>
 <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Runs)
    </th>
 <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Hits)
    </th>
```

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{

<tr>

<td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PlayerName)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PlateAppearance)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Runs)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Hits)
    </td>
</tr>
}
</table>
```

**Also tried**

```
    var playerGameStats = (from pgs in db.PlayerGameStats
                               join p in db.Players on pgs.Player_id equals p.id_player
                               where pgs.SeasonId == 11 && pgs.GameNumber == 19
                               select new Player_Game_Stats
                              {
                                  p.PlayerName,
                                  pgs.PlateAppearance,
                                  pgs.Runs,
                                  pgs.Hits
                              }).ToList();


        return View(playerGameStats);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public ActionResult Details(int gid=19, int sid = 11)
{

    var playerGameStats = from pgs in db.PlayerGameStats
                          join p in db.Players on pgs.Player_id equals p.id_player
                          where pgs.SeasonId == 11 && pgs.GameNumber == 19
                          select new TitansMVCWithBootStrap.Models.Player_Game_Stats
                          {
                              PlayerName = p.PlayerName,
                              PlateAppearance = pgs.PlateAppearance,
                              Runs = pgs.Runs,
                              Hits = pgs.Hits
                          };

    return View(playerGameStats);

}
```

Comment: I get the following error. `Cannot initialize type 'TitansMVCWithBootStrap.Models.Player_Game_Stats' with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable' \TitansBootStrap\TitansMVCWithBootStrap\TitansMVCWithBootStrap\Controllers\PlayerGameStatsController.cs TitansMVCWithBootStrap`

Comment: Also tried 'var playerGameStats = (from pgs in db.PlayerGameStats
join p in db.Players on pgs.Player_id equals p.id_player
where pgs.SeasonId == 11 && pgs.GameNumber == 19
select new Player_Game_Stats
   {
    p.PlayerName,
    pgs.PlateAppearance,
    pgs.Runs,
    pgs.Hits
    }).ToList();

 return View(playerGameStats);`

Comment: When you create the new object of type "Player_Game_Stats", you need to put "PropertyName" = "Value", like this: select new Player_Game_Stats { PlayerName = p.PlayerName, ... }

Comment: Try you suggestion but no luck. `select new TitansMVCWithBootStrap.Models.Player_Game_Stats
{
PlayerName = p.PlayerName,
PlateAppearance = pgs.PlateAppearance,
Runs = pgs.Runs,
Hits = pgs.Hits
};` **TitansMVCWithBootStrap.Models.Player_Game_Stats' does not contain a definition for 'PlayerName**

Comment: Players has a one to many relationship with Player_Game_Stats. So a player can have multiple entries in Player_Game_Stats, I am using the where clause to limit the results. This query works in LinqPad but not in MVC `from pgs in Player_Game_Stats
join p in Players on pgs.Player_id equals p.Id_player
where pgs.SeasonId == 11 && pgs.GameNumber == 19
select new
{
p.PlayerName,
pgs.PlateAppearance,
pgs.Runs,
pgs.Hits
}
`

Comment: You need to add the property "PlayerName" in the model "Player_Game_Stats"